# How to have a div [box] as responsive with text in it

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want is that the text-box class should be responsive, so when I change the width, the width and height would be the same as a square and that the text would change relative to it so that the text does not come out of the text-box. As you can see, the text box has come out of the float box and container when you change the width. Thank you for your help it means a lot.

```css
.container {
    border: solid 1px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 1fr;
}

.float-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 75vh;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.text-box {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 30vw !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50vh;
    border: solid 1px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 2px 3px rgb(128, 128, 128);
    box-shadow: 10px 11px 2px 3px grey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.texts {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text-box p {
    font-size: 1vw;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="float-box">
            <div class="text-box">
                <div class="texts">
                <p class="text-highlight">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
                        natus magni distinctio sit eaque laudantium, nulla quos sed
                        architecto repellat dolore ut voluptatum atque debitis.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum,
                    consectetur sit! Beatae sint, nobis odit a aspernatur ab repellendus
                    dolorem necessitatibus voluptatums.
                </p>
                <span class="success"><p>Icon <h4>The best of 2020</h4></p></span>
                    <p class="text-highlight bigger">
                        Noget Info Om Virksomheden
                    </p>
                <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure,
                        necessitatibus.
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box2"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check if It works for You.**

```css
.container {
    border: solid 1px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 1fr;
}

.float-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 75vh;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.text-box {
    position: absolute;
    /* right: 10px; */
    /* margin: 20px 0; */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /* padding: 40px; */
    width: 30vw !important;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 50vh;
    border: solid 1px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 2px 3px rgb(128, 128, 128);
    box-shadow: 10px 11px 2px 3px grey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.texts {
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.text-box p {
    font-size: 1vw;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="float-box">
            <div class="text-box">
                <div class="texts">
                <p class="text-highlight">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
                        natus magni distinctio sit eaque laudantium, nulla quos sed
                        architecto repellat dolore ut voluptatum atque debitis.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum,
                    consectetur sit! Beatae sint, nobis odit a aspernatur ab repellendus
                    dolorem necessitatibus voluptatums.
                </p>
                <span class="success"><p>Icon <h4>The best of 2020</h4></p></span>
                    <p class="text-highlight bigger">
                        Noget Info Om Virksomheden
                    </p>
                <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure,
                        necessitatibus.
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box2"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***If you don't want scrollable text, just comment out `overflow: scroll` and replace it by `overflow: hidden` in `class text-box`***